# Properly matched parentheses with restrictions

Tags: algorithms

I'm practicing solving programming problems, and I can't manage with this one since a week:

> For a given $n\le2000$ and sequences $L,R$ with values in $\left\{1,2,...,2n \right\}$ count the number of properly matched parentheses words length $2n$, that have left parentheses on the positions from $L$ and right parentheses on the positions from $R$. Give the result modulo $10^9+7$.

I really don't have any ideas. Since $n$ is small, maybe some dynamic programming approach will do that? But I don't see any recursion that will help counting these objects. Strange is $10^9+7$, maybe it's worth saying that this is a prime number.

I will give one example, just in case, to clarify:

for $n=4, L=\langle 1,7 \rangle, R=\langle 3\rangle$ the answer is $2$, because the pattern is: $[?]???[?$, and there are two words that fit this pattern: $[[][]][]$ and $[[]][][]$.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

More information on these sequences can be found under this Wikipedia entry for [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). The algorithm to use is [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). The idea is to use a table to record the number of sequences that fit a given pattern and populate it recursively, with the base cases being either empty patterns or patterns of length two. The procedure recurses by choosing the length of the first balanced prefix, and filling that and the remainder recursively. The prefix can range from length two to the entire pattern. The number of entries in the table is quadratic in the length of the pattern, which makes it possible to treat cases like $n=2000.$

I present two solutions in Perl. The first one actually outputs all matching sequences and the second one just calculates their number.

**Output all matching sequences:**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

my %memo = ();

sub search {
    my (@spat) = @_;

    return [''] if scalar(@spat) == 0;

    my $key = join '-', @spat;
    return $memo{$key} if exists($memo{$key});


    if(scalar(@spat) == 2){
      if(($spat[0] eq '?' || $spat[0] eq '[') &&
         ($spat[1] eq '?' || $spat[1] eq ']')){
          $memo{$key} = [ '[]' ];
          return $memo{$key};
      }

      $memo{$key} = [];
      return $memo{$key};
    }

    my $res = [];

    for(my $pos=2; $pos<=scalar(@spat); $pos+=2){
      if(($spat[0] eq '?' || $spat[0] eq '[') &&
         ($spat[$pos-1] eq '?' || $spat[$pos-1] eq ']')){
          my $first = search(@spat[1..($pos-2)]);
          my $rest = search(@spat[$pos..$#spat]);

          foreach my $s1 (@$first){
            foreach my $s2 (@$rest){
                push @$res, "[$s1]$s2";
            }
          }
      }
    }


    $memo{$key} = $res;
    return $res;
}


MAIN: {
    my $pattern = shift || '[?]???[?';

    if($pattern !~ /^[\[\]\?]+$/){
      print STDERR "permitted characters are ?, [ and ]\n";
      exit -1;
    }

    if(length($pattern) % 2 > 1){
      print STDERR "even length pattern please\n";
      exit -2;
    }

    my @spat = split(//, $pattern);

    my $res = search @spat;

    foreach my $parens (@$res){
      print "$parens\n";
    }
}
```

**Calculate the total count of matching sequences:**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

my %memo = ();

sub search {
    my (@spat) = @_;

    return 1 if scalar(@spat) == 0;

    my $key = join '-', @spat;
    return $memo{$key} if exists($memo{$key});


    if(scalar(@spat) == 2){
      if(($spat[0] eq '?' || $spat[0] eq '[') &&
         ($spat[1] eq '?' || $spat[1] eq ']')){
          $memo{$key} = 1;
          return $memo{$key};
      }

      $memo{$key} = 0;
      return $memo{$key};
    }

    my $res = 0;

    for(my $pos=2; $pos<=scalar(@spat); $pos+=2){
      if(($spat[0] eq '?' || $spat[0] eq '[') &&
         ($spat[$pos-1] eq '?' || $spat[$pos-1] eq ']')){
          my $first = search(@spat[1..($pos-2)]);
          my $rest = search(@spat[$pos..$#spat]);

          $res += $first*$rest;
      }
    }


    $memo{$key} = $res;
    return $res;
}


MAIN: {
    my $pattern = shift || '[?]???[?';

    if($pattern !~ /^[\[\]\?]+$/){
      print STDERR "permitted characters are ?, [ and ]\n";
      exit -1;
    }

    if(length($pattern) % 2 > 1){
      print STDERR "even length pattern please\n";
      exit -2;
    }

    my @spat = split(//, $pattern);

    my $res = search @spat;
    print "$res\n";
}
```